# How to do a page slide transition on form submit?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a series of forms in HTML pages that I want to `slide in` and `slide out` when the form is submitted and the page reloads. Is this possible with jquery?  Is this possible to do when the page loads on each page or will I need to use AJAX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible, you just set a negative margin to the page, and slide it in on page load.
and then animate the page on submit click and submit the form progrmmatically:

<kbd>**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/sb5y0jvj/)**</kbd>

HTML:

```
<form id="theForm" action="/three">
    <div id="slidable">
        <button id="bt_submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
#slidable {
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    border:5px solid red;
    margin-left:-300px;
}
```

JQUERY

```
$(function () {
    $("#slidable").animate({
        "margin-left": 0
    }, 500);
    $("#bt_submit").click(function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        $("#slidable").animate({
            "margin-left": -300
        }, 500, function () {
            $("#theForm").submit();
        });
    });
});
```

- **the example works with a red square, but you can as well adjust the selectors to select the whole page.**